# PostgreSQL: How to delete dynamically created table using SQL

Tags: postgresql

I am developing a windows application and using Postgres as backend database. At some point in my application i am dynamically creating table e.g Table1, then Table2 and so on. In this way i have many dynamic table in my database. Now i provide a button "Clean Database", so i need to remove all those dynamic tables using SQL query. Should some one guide me how to write SQL Query that automatically delete all such tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to say

```
DROP TABLE {tablename}
```

for each dynamically created table. Try that and see if it works.